# Why Windows Phone 8 emulator does not run in Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, virtual-machine

I have downloaded Windows Phone sdk and but it gave me an error about Hyper-V and asked me to restart. I restarted the computer and start a new windows phone 8 project and when I debug it gave me this error.

> Can't start Windows Phone Emulator
>
> The Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V. Your PC is missing the following pre-requisites required to run Hyper-V
>   - Windows 8 Professional (64 bit)

Is there any way I could get this work?

Comment: did you even bother TRYING to read the error message? you need to enable hyper-v.

Comment: it asks me to install windows 8 pro. but I do not have the facility

Comment: then you're not going to be doing much developing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [system requirements documentation for the windows Phone 8 emulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) states that you need a 64-bit version of **Windows 8 Pro edition** or higher. I suspect you do not have a Pro edition.

You can still develop apps for Windows Phone 8 on a non-Pro edition, but you can't use the emulator - you have to debug on a registered Windows Phone 8 phone.

Answer (score 2):

just do a simple task
go this path
Control Panel --> Program And Features --> Turn Windows features on or off --> Be Sure That Hyper-V has been checked
now restart your computer

Answer (score 1):

To allow Hyper-V (assuming you have a windows 8.1 Pro or windows 10 pro)

Go to cmd, run it as admin and tape the following :

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

To turn it off (Because you will quickly get into some problems while not debugging)

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```